# What to do when a question changes?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, the content of a question may change.

For example, an author of a general question (*old_question_1*) precises the topic of a question (*new_question_1*) and at the same time starts an another question (*question_2*), which is a special case of the *old_question_1*.

What has the answerer of the *old_question_1* to do, when his answer doesn't anymore fit to the *new_question_1* but to the *question_2*? Do the answerer should make a copy of his answer in the *question_2* thread and delete the answer in the thread of *new_qustion_1* or are there better alternatives?

Comment: In an ideal world, this should not happen. Specially editors should try hard to preserve the meaning that the original poster (OP) of the question had intended. Unfortunately, it can happen that the OP learns that E wanted to ask something different and changes Eir question.

Answer (score 3):

Questions should not change their meaning when there are already answers, or those answers would be invalidated.

If a user asked a question, edited it after it was answered, and asked another question for which the answers are a subset of the answers for the first question, I would:

- Revert the first question to the previous reversion
- Closed the second question as duplicate of the first question

Then, it depends from what exactly the questions ask. For sure, I would revert the question change done after it was answered, if the change modifies its meaning.